# Color options disappear in Settings > Style when using chart.bg_color or input.color() + color.rgb()

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

when using **chart.bg_color** or deriving a new color with **color.rgb() from a user input input.color()** for filling two plots with **fill()**, the **color options disappear in Settings > Style**. Is this normal behavior and has a reason to it or is this a bug? I attached a basic sample code with four different color-schemes. Fill 1-3 provoke the bug. For testing reasons I also added Fill 4, to show that the color options re-appear when not using chart.bg_color or color.rgb().

Appreciate your help.

Phil

```
//@version=5
indicator("Color Settings Bug", overlay=true)

// User input colors for up and down
i_clrup = input.color(color.new(#29ebd0, 0), title="Color Up")
i_clrdn = input.color(color.new(#ec5c74, 0), title="Color Down")

// Two moving averages
ma_fast = ta.sma(close, 10)
ma_slow = ta.sma(close, 50)
ma_trend = ma_fast > ma_slow ? 1 : ma_fast < ma_slow ? -1 : 0 // trend for the fill color logic
top_ma = math.max(ma_fast, ma_slow) // upper ma for the fill color logic
bottom_ma = math.min(ma_fast, ma_slow) // lower ma for the fill color logic

// MA plots
p1 = plot(ma_fast, "MA Fast", display = display.none, editable = true) // editable true, so the colors should appear in the Style-tab in the indicator settings
p2 = plot(ma_slow, "MA Slow", display = display.none, editable = true) // editable true, so the colors should appear in the Style-tab in the indicator settings

// Colors for the fill between the two MAs based on the user input (in a more complex script needed to derive certain colors and color shades from a single user input)
bgclrup = color.rgb(color.r(i_clrup), color.g(i_clrup), color.b(i_clrup), 40)
bgclrdn = color.rgb(color.r(i_clrdn), color.g(i_clrdn), color.b(i_clrdn), 40)

// Fill 1: rgb-color from input color + chart.bg_color --> Breaks color settings in style tab in indicator settings
fill(p1, p2
 , top_value = top_ma
 , bottom_value = bottom_ma
 , top_color = ma_trend == 1 ? color.new(chart.bg_color, 100) : bgclrdn
 , bottom_color = ma_trend == 1 ? bgclrup : color.new(chart.bg_color, 100)
 , title = "Background Gradient"
 , editable = true)

// Fill 2: rgb-color from input color + normal color --> Breaks color settings in style tab in indicator settings
//fill(p1, p2
// , top_value = top_ma
// , bottom_value = bottom_ma
// , top_color = ma_trend == 1 ? color.new(color.green, 100) : bgclrdn
// , bottom_color = ma_trend == 1 ? bgclrup : color.new(color.red, 100)
// , title = "Background Gradient"
// , editable = true) 

// Fill 3: chart.bg_color + normal color --> Breaks color settings in style tab in indicator settings
//fill(p1, p2
// , top_value = top_ma
// , bottom_value = bottom_ma
// , top_color = ma_trend == 1 ? color.new(chart.bg_color, 100) : color.red
// , bottom_color = ma_trend == 1 ? color.green : color.new(chart.bg_color, 100)
// , title = "Background Gradient"
// , editable = true)

// Fill 4 - No derived colors - Works
//fill(p1, p2
// , top_value = top_ma
// , bottom_value = bottom_ma
// , top_color = ma_trend == 1 ? color.new(color.green, 100) : color.red
// , bottom_color = ma_trend == 1 ? color.green : color.new(color.red, 100)
// , title = "Background Gradient"
// , editable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script has calculated colors, then the color widget in the style tab won't be available.

You can read more details from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Colors.html#color-selection-through-script-settings).

> If your script uses a calculated color, i.e., a color where at least
> one of its RGBA components can only be known at runtime, then the
> “Settings/Style” tab will NOT offer users the usual color widgets they
> can use to modify your plot colors. Plots of the same script not using
> calculated colors will also be affected.